# Zoom - Problems with sound after updating Mint

Tags: linux-mint, zoom

I updated Mint to 20.3 and since then I have some strange issue with Zoom 5.14.2, whenever some music is played if some instruments are loud it cuts the microphone. I tried all the options in the Zoom App but cannot find what the problem is, it was working fine before updating Mint so I'm thinking it might be some problem with the update? Any idea how I could fix that? I thought about downgrading but I'm in the middle of a seminar with 2 sessions per day and I have no time to reinstall everything...

Comment: it's very likely on the zoom side of things – detects noise and turns of the microphone. That's not a feature present in Linux audio stacks as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That's a noise gate kicking in. According to the [release notes](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360042041011-Release-notes-for-Zoom-Room-Appliances) 5.13 has "advanced noise suppression", and 5.14.2 contains unspecified "minor bug fixes". You can [adjust the settings](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360046244692-Configuring-professional-audio-settings-for-Zoom-Meetings).

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks, I did adjust the settings as per the documentation but nothing is working.

Comment: There's no setting to turn it off entirely?